# IntelliJ & GitHub: How to create an organization-based repository

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I am a noob at both GitHub and IntelliJ, please answer in that context and be patient.

GOAL:
I need to create a repository for my IntelliJ project in my organization, not my personal account, and be able to Admin it.

NOTE:  I do NOT have admin rights for the organization, but I can create projects on it through the GitHub interface and setup a team for it with Admin rights.  So, the goal **should be feasible**.

PROBLEM:

- I am using IntelliJ (and its integrated GitHub support, not a separate windows github app install).
- When I use the IntelliJ "Share the Project on GitHub" I am not given the option to choose whether to place the repository in the organization, it automatically places it in my account's list of repositories.
- Then if in the GitHub website I try to transfer ownership from my account to the organization, it moves it but I lose all Admin rights.  I tried to add a team I defined in the organization as collaborators to see if I could grant myself Admin rights through the team before I transfer ownership but the team does not appear.

2nd (related) PROBLEM:

- Files committed from IntelliJ show as successful in IntelliJ but do not display in the Code section of the GitHub website.  The message in that page mentions creating or uploading a file even though in theory IntelliJ did that.

QUESTION:

- Is IntelliJ's GitHub integration usable, especially for organization-based repositories?   Or should I install the windows command-line GitHub app and do all of my version control from there?
- If the first, is there a good tutorial for creating org-based repositories in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION (I figured it out):

1. Create the project repository inside the organization.
2. Click on the repository to open it.  Copy the URL.
3. In IntelliJ create a new project from VCS.  Past the URL and hit CLONE.
4. Add your project contents, commit and push.

Much simpler than I expected... once figured out.

Comment: I also had to allow access for IntelliJ in https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/58566862bd2a5ff748fb